# Automated Deploys With Embedded Jetty

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, continuous-deployment

I've taken a fancy to including Jetty with my applications instead of deploying to a container. But there's one big issue I've run in to: How can I automated the deploy? When the container ran standalone it was enough to copy the war file over the old and it would get picked up. With Jetty as a dependency I run it at the command line and control-c it when done. I can't think of an easy way to automate this. Is there a better solution than creating scripts to manage the job, stop the container and restart, keep track of job id, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Look into setting up a `DeploymentManager` and `AppProvider` that suits your needs.

```java
    // === jetty deploy ===
    DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
    deployer.setContexts(contexts);
    deployer.setContextAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$");

    WebAppProvider webapp_provider = new WebAppProvider();
    webapp_provider.setMonitoredDirName(jetty_base + "/webapps");
    webapp_provider.setDefaultsDescriptor(jetty_home + "/etc/webdefault.xml");
    webapp_provider.setScanInterval(1);
    webapp_provider.setExtractWars(true);

    deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_provider);
    server.addBean(deployer);
```

Full example can be found in [`LikeJettyXml.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.9.v20150224/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java#L155-L170)